# Hooking Kernel sys_read() Not Affecting Text Editors

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

So, I've been doing a little kernel module programming and I have a working module installed that screens text files with a certain name and replaces any occurrence of a word with another. I do this by tracking the files I want in the module through hooking `sys_open()` and then I do the rewrite in my hook of `sys_read()`.

However, the effect is only seen when I `cat` the file (or maybe use `awk` or `print` from bash), but opening the screened file in a text editor just displays the unfiltered text.

My question is, why doesn't hooking `sys_read()` affect the output of text editors? I have tried: vi, vim, gedit and nano. Are they obtaining the file contents in another way? I know it is calling `sys_read()` because my `printk` debug message appears in `dmesg`, but maybe it is throwing away the read buffer and using another technique?

Just wondering what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your text editor is using a separate temporary file when you are editing the file and only saving it under the real  name while closing/exiting the editor.